# In shell script, my file which is .TXT file which contain names . I want to execute the command echo $firstname it print lastname

Tags: shell

Condition: don't have to use a single variable.
File.txt
Fox chasin
Sandra jhonsan
Nancy linoy

echo $fox
Output : chasin

Comment: I have not the slightest idea what you want to achieve; please be a bit more explicit. Define your input, explain your desired output, and post the output you get instead. Also, please format your code readably. I don't understand what your command `echo $fox Output : chasin` is supposed to do.

Comment: `grep -i fox File.txt` (not echo)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
  do
    firstname=${line%[[:blank:]]*}
    lastname=${line##*[[:blank:]]}

    echo $firstname

done < File.txt
```

Comment: no I want to  output the last name by echo $firstname .

Comment: as you see there is also a variable $lastname. you can swap the names. variable names doesn't matter